# Non-blocking rate-limited ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, rate-limiting

I am hitting an HTTP server concurrently with multiple connections. I'd like to throttle the clients in response to servers indicating that requests are coming in too fast. I do not wish to change the HTTP library I am using but rather I'd like to extend it.

To that end, **how do I implement a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with the following constraints?**

- The executor has an optional rate limit.
- When the rate-limit is disabled, it executes tasks as quickly as possible (normal behavior for a `ThreadPoolExecutor`).
- When the rate-limit is enabled, it may execute up to `N` tasks per second.
- The rate-limit applies across all executor threads, not per-thread.
- No bursts are allowed. Meaning, if the limit is 10 requests per second I expect one request to begin every 100ms. I don't want all threads firing at once then remaining idle for the rest of the second.
- The rate-limit is dynamic. If a request fails, the rate decreases. If a request succeeds, the rate increases.
- Threads are considered idle when no tasks are ready for execution (taking the rate limit into consideration). Meaning, I expect `ThreadPoolExecutor` to flag these threads are idle and spin them down as it sees fit as opposed to blocking the threads until the rate-limit is met. On the flip side, threads should spin up again once it's time to execute the next task.

### What I've Looked Into

- [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [DelayedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) assume that the execution delay is known at event-queuing time, whereas in my case the rate may change between the time a task is queued and the time it is executed.
- [RateLimiter](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) will probably form part of the answer but is not enough on its own.

Comment: I guess the downvoters did not like the lack of evidence for your own effort in your original post. But I can hardly see which sort of evidence one could provide for this algorithmically complex task. Good luck in finding the solution.

Comment: Meta commentary has no place in questions, do not edit those back in. Questions are meant to last beyond your specific needs, for future visitors to benefit from, and future visitors do not care about the process here.

Comment: @OlegSklyar FYI, I got it working. Answer posted below.

Comment: @Gili Nice job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- It isn't possible to have a solution that is completely non-blocking. Even `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` keeps at least one thread around waiting for the queue to return a new task.
- `ThreadPoolExecutor` sits on top of a `BlockingQueue`. When there are no tasks left, it blocks on `BlockingQueue.take()`
- The solution has 3 moving pieces:

1. A rate limiter.
2. A `BlockingQueue` that hides elements until the rate limiter allows their consumption.
3. A `ThreadPoolExecutor` that sits on top of the `BlockingQueue`.

### The Rate Limiter

I provide my own rate limiter based on the [Token Bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) algorithm to overcome `RateLimiter`'s [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27711962/14731). The source-code can be found [here](https://github.com/cowwoc/token-bucket).

---

### The BlockingQueue

I implementing a `BlockingDeque` (which extends `BlockingQueue`) because in the future I want to try pushing failed tasks back to the front of the queue.

RateLimitedBlockingDeque.java

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static org.bitbucket.cowwoc.requirements.core.Requirements.requireThat;

/**
 * A blocking deque of elements, in which an element can only be taken when the deque-wide delay has expired.
 * <p>
 * The optional capacity bound constructor argument serves as a way to prevent excessive expansion. The capacity, if
 * unspecified, is equal to {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE}.
 * <p>
 * Even though methods that take elements, such as {@code take} or {@code poll}, respect the deque-wide delay the
 * remaining methods treat them as normal elements. For example, the {@code size} method returns the count of both
 * expired and unexpired elements.
 * <p>
 * This class and its iterator implement all of the <em>optional</em> methods of the {@link Collection} and {@link
 * Iterator} interfaces.
 *
 * @param <E> the type of elements in the deque
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class RateLimitedBlockingDeque<E> implements BlockingDeque<E>
{
    private final int capacity;
    private final LinkedBlockingDeque<E> delegate;
    private final Bucket rateLimit = new Bucket();

    /**
     * Creates a {@code RateLimitedBlockingDeque} with a capacity of {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE}.
     */
    public RateLimitedBlockingDeque()
    {
        this.capacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        this.delegate = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@code RateLimitedBlockingDeque} with the given (fixed) capacity.
     *
     * @param capacity the capacity of this deque
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code capacity} is less than 1
     */
    public RateLimitedBlockingDeque(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.delegate = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(capacity);
    }

    /**
     * @return the capacity of the deque
     */
    public int getCapacity()
    {
        return capacity;
    }

    /**
     * Indicates the rate at which elements may be taken from the queue.
     *
     * @param elements the number of elements that may be taken per {@code period}
     * @param period   indicates how often elements may be taken
     * @throws NullPointerException     if {@code period} is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the requested rate is greater than element per nanosecond
     */
    public void setRate(long elements, Duration period)
    {
        synchronized (rateLimit)
        {
            Limit newLimit = new Limit(elements, period, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            if (rateLimit.getLimits().isEmpty())
                rateLimit.addLimit(newLimit);
            else
            {
                Limit oldLimit = rateLimit.getLimits().iterator().next();
                rateLimit.replaceLimit(oldLimit, newLimit);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows consumption of elements without limit.
     */
    public void removeRate()
    {
        synchronized (rateLimit)
        {
            rateLimit.removeAllLimits();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addFirst(E e)
    {
        delegate.addFirst(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void addLast(E e)
    {
        delegate.addLast(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offerFirst(E e)
    {
        return delegate.offerFirst(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offerLast(E e)
    {
        return delegate.offerLast(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void putFirst(E e) throws InterruptedException
    {
        delegate.putFirst(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void putLast(E e) throws InterruptedException
    {
        delegate.putLast(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offerFirst(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
    {
        return delegate.offerFirst(e, timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offerLast(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
    {
        return delegate.offerLast(e, timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public E removeFirst()
    {
        if (rateLimit.tryConsume())
            return delegate.removeFirst();
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    @Override
    public E removeLast()
    {
        if (rateLimit.tryConsume())
            return delegate.removeLast();
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    @Override
    public E pollFirst()
    {
        if (rateLimit.tryConsume())
            return delegate.pollFirst();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public E pollLast()
    {
        if (rateLimit.tryConsume())
            return delegate.pollLast();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public E takeFirst() throws InterruptedException
    {
        rateLimit.consume();
        return delegate.takeFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public E takeLast() throws InterruptedException
    {
        rateLimit.consume();
        return delegate.takeLast();
    }

    @Override
    public E pollFirst(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (rateLimit.consume(1, timeout, unit))
            return delegate.pollFirst(timeout, unit);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public E pollLast(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (rateLimit.consume(1, timeout, unit))
            return delegate.pollLast(timeout, unit);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public E getFirst()
    {
        return delegate.getFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public E getLast()
    {
        return delegate.getLast();
    }

    @Override
    public E peekFirst()
    {
        return delegate.peekFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public E peekLast()
    {
        return delegate.peekLast();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeFirstOccurrence(Object o)
    {
        return delegate.removeFirstOccurrence(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeLastOccurrence(Object o)
    {
        return delegate.removeLastOccurrence(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e)
    {
        return delegate.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e)
    {
        return delegate.offer(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException
    {
        putLast(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
    {
        return delegate.offer(e, timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public E remove()
    {
        return removeFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public E poll()
    {
        return pollFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public E take() throws InterruptedException
    {
        return takeFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public E poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException
    {
        return pollFirst(timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public E element()
    {
        return getFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public E peek()
    {
        return peekFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public int remainingCapacity()
    {
        return delegate.remainingCapacity();
    }

    @Override
    public int drainTo(Collection<? super E> c)
    {
        int result = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            E next = pollFirst();
            if (next == null)
                break;
            c.add(next);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int drainTo(Collection<? super E> c, int maxElements)
    {
        int result = 0;
        do
        {
            E next = pollFirst();
            if (next == null)
                break;
            c.add(next);
        }
        while (result < maxElements);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void push(E e)
    {
        addFirst(e);
    }

    @Override
    public E pop()
    {
        return removeFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o)
    {
        return removeFirstOccurrence(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o)
    {
        return delegate.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray()
    {
        return delegate.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
    {
        return delegate.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return delegate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear()
    {
        delegate.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return wrap(delegate.iterator());
    }

    /**
     * @param delegateIterator the iterator to delegate to
     * @return an iterator that respects the rate-limit
     */
    private Iterator<E> wrap(Iterator<E> delegateIterator)
    {
        return new Iterator<E>()
        {
            private E previousElement = null;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return delegateIterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public E next()
            {
                return delegateIterator.next();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                if (previousElement == null)
                    throw new IllegalStateException("next() not invoked, or remove() already invoked");
                try
                {
                    rateLimit.consume();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
                delegateIterator.remove();
                previousElement = null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> descendingIterator()
    {
        return wrap(delegate.descendingIterator());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
    {
        requireThat("c", c).isNotNull().isNotEqualTo("this", this);
        boolean modified = false;
        for (E e: c)
            if (add(e))
                modified = true;
        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return delegate.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        return delegate.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        Iterator<E> i = iterator();
        boolean modified = true;
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            E element = i.next();
            if (c.contains(element))
            {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
    {
        Iterator<E> i = iterator();
        boolean modified = true;
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            E element = i.next();
            if (!c.contains(element))
            {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return delegate.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return delegate.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Source code link throwing 404 not found . could you share if possible?

Comment: Thank you for the code. i have one doubt. since here you are not using any external persistent queue like redis or jms will this scale for the volume? i.e you need to process 100 RPS but what if incoming req is 100000 RPS .  what will happen in this case?

Comment: @thaveethugce `Bucket` is thread-safe so you'll get one thread at a time acquiring a token and everyone else blocking was waiting on the mutex or waiting for the next token to become available. You can invoke `Bucket.consume()` from JMH to figure out the average number of tokens your machine will be able to consume per second. It should be pretty high.

Comment: Thanks for your time explaining me the basics. i am Sorry still i am not clear in this. what will happen if more request flooded ? at one point of time we need to reject the request? how many request can be waiting to get token ? will more threads waiting can leads to memory overflow and requests getting rejected? assume QPS allowed in rate limiting is 1000 but incoming request is really huge like Million / sec

Comment: @thaveethugce It depends on which class you are looking at. `Bucket` does not have any sort of limit. Trying to acquire a token will block the thread until your turn is reached. If you are talking about `RateLimitedBlockingDequeue` then you can see from the Javadoc that it has a corresponding `capacity`. If you try to push more tasks onto the deque than `capacity` allows then you will get the behavior specified by `BlockingDeque.add()` (i.e. `IllegalStateException` will get thrown)

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    RateFriendlyThreadPoolExecutor executor = new RateFriendlyThreadPoolExecutor(3, 5, 1, SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(100));
    executor.setRate(10);
    executor.setMinRate(1);
    executor.setMaxRate(100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int lap = i;
        executor.execute(() -> System.out.printf("%03d (%s) - %s - %s%n", lap, executor.getRate(), LocalDateTime.now(), Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(60, SECONDS);
}
```

Output:

```
002 (10) - 2023-05-27T23:03:37.659658800 - pool-1-thread-3
000 (11) - 2023-05-27T23:03:37.659658800 - pool-1-thread-1
001 (11) - 2023-05-27T23:03:37.744859100 - pool-1-thread-2
105 (11) - 2023-05-27T23:03:37.930152500 - main
103 (12) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.037876400 - pool-1-thread-4
104 (12) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.130058800 - pool-1-thread-5
003 (12) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.221655300 - pool-1-thread-3
004 (12) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.314020700 - pool-1-thread-1
005 (12) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.406202700 - pool-1-thread-2
006 (12) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.573508200 - pool-1-thread-4
007 (13) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.665875900 - pool-1-thread-5
008 (13) - 2023-05-27T23:03:38.742695200 - pool-1-thread-3
```

Implementation:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import static java.lang.Math.min;
import static java.lang.System.nanoTime;

public class RateFriendlyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private AtomicInteger rate = new AtomicInteger();
    private AtomicInteger minRate = new AtomicInteger();
    private AtomicInteger maxRate = new AtomicInteger();
    private AtomicLong leapTime = new AtomicLong();
    private ReentrantLock rateLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public RateFriendlyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, (r, e) -> overflow(r, (RateFriendlyThreadPoolExecutor) e));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable rannable) {
        super.execute(() -> executeWithDelay(rannable));
    }

    protected void executeWithDelay(Runnable runnable) {
        int rateSnapshot = rate.get();
        limitRate(rateSnapshot, leapTime, rateLock);
        try {

            runnable.run();

            rate.compareAndSet(rateSnapshot, min(rateSnapshot + 1, maxRate.get()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!isThrottled(e))
                throw e;
            System.out.println("throttled at rate " + rateSnapshot);
            rate.set(minRate.get());
            execute(runnable);
        }
    }

    // works for parallel streams like a charm
    public static void limitRate(int rate, AtomicLong leapTime, ReentrantLock rateLock) {
        if (rate == 0)
            return;
        long targetLeapTime = 1_000_000_000 / rate;
        rateLock.lock();
        try {
            long timeSnapshot = nanoTime();
            long waitTime = targetLeapTime - (timeSnapshot - leapTime.get());
            if (waitTime > 0) {

                if (waitTime > 1_000_000)
                    LockSupport.parkNanos(waitTime);
                else
                    while (timeSnapshot + waitTime > nanoTime())
                        /* busy wait */;

                leapTime.set(timeSnapshot + waitTime);
            } else {
                leapTime.set(timeSnapshot);
            }
        } finally {
            rateLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private static void overflow(Runnable r, RateFriendlyThreadPoolExecutor e) {
        if (!e.isShutdown())
            e.executeWithDelay(r);
    }

    private boolean isThrottled(Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage().contains("Reduce your rate");
    }

    public AtomicInteger getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(int rate) {
        this.rate.set(rate);
        minRate.compareAndSet(0, rate);
        maxRate.compareAndSet(0, rate);
    }

    public AtomicInteger getMinRate() {
        return minRate;
    }

    public void setMinRate(int minRate) {
        this.minRate.set(minRate);
    }

    public AtomicInteger getMaxRate() {
        return maxRate;
    }

    public void setMaxRate(int maxRate) {
        this.maxRate.set(maxRate);
    }
}
```